# Magnolia CMS NextJS hybrid SSG development

Tags: next.js, magnolia

I am trying to look into the Magnolia CMS NextJS hybrid SSG project. There is a boilerplate code for a page pages/[[pathname]] which will generate static content and paths for all the pages we add in the pages app in the admincentral. This works perfectly for page authors. When we use content from content types, how do we get that into a component?

When I look at props a component receive, it only contains the values I have specified in the page editor while adding the component.

I would like to be able to develop a component which can be added to a page via editor, which lists a list of content from a content type. Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is supported.

The key is that you want the REST Delivery Endpoint to return the content from any linked content in your content app. You can do this by adding `referenceResolvers` to the endpoint configuration.

Here is an example of an AssetReference resolver. https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/DEMOS/repos/minimal-headless-spa-demos/browse/magnolia/light-modules/spa-lm/restEndpoints/delivery/pages_v1.yaml#18

You will want to add a jcrReferenceResolver which specifies your propertyName. See the docs here:
https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Developing/API/Delivery-API/Resolving-references-with-the-delivery-endpoint.html#_example_configuration

Comment: Your answer only touches the REST endpoint configuration side. I am interested in the NextJS hybrid editable page template which is a headless SPA.

Comment: It depends a bit on the usecase - in my above answer I assume that you have a link field in your component, and the author uses it to link to a content item. 

In that case, once you have the reference resolver configured, then the props to your component will include the content of the linked item.